# Bash - check if variable is set if different servers, error

Tags: bash, variables

I am doing the same check (if variable is set) on two servers, both linux:

> x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

the code is:

```
my_var="hello"
[ ! -v "${my_var}"  ]
```

In one server, there is no error and check works as expected.
On the other server I get the syntax **error**:

> bash: [: -v: unary operator expected

Same behavior if I run the code via `.sh` script or directly in the bash terminal.

what is the reason, and what could be a generic solution?

Comment: How is `$my_var` related to the variable `$hello`?

Comment: gosh! Thanks that was me being dumb on writing the example. already updated!

Comment: What is the Bash version of each of the servers? Are you really sure you are actually running Bash? (For example, many beginners run `sh scriptname` and are then confused when Bash features are not available.)

Comment: And what's the value of the variable $hello? `-v ${my_var}` uses the value of the variable, i.e. it tests $hello.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[ -v var ]` was added in 4.2, see e.g. [the list of changes in the Bash Hackers wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges?s%5B%5D=nameref#conditional_expressions_and_test_command).

```
$ ./bash4.1 -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION; var=x; [ -v var ] && echo hi'
4.1.0(1)-release
./bash4.1: line 0: [: -v: unary operator expected

$ ./bash4.2.0 -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION; var=x; [ -v var ] && echo hi'
4.2.0(1)-release
hi
```

So you're probably running an old version on one of the hosts and would need to upgrade to use the `-v` test. (Anyway, Bash 4.2 is about 10 years old now, released 2011-02-13.)

Alternatively, use the standard `${variable+word}` expansion, which would also work with other shells, like Dash which you'll find as `/bin/sh` on Debian and Ubuntu.

```
if [ "${var+set}" = set ]; then
    echo 'var is set (but may be empty)'
else
    echo 'var is not set'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But I can't update the bash, it's not my server :)

Comment: "tell your sysadmin to update their Bash. (Bash 4.2 is about 10 years old now, released 2011-02-13.)" that doesn't really work, as MacOS ships old bash by default. you could argue to download a more recent version via homebrew but you can't expect that to always be done everywhere and as such you can't use the regular #/bin/bash

Comment: @RickRackow, they said they were using Linux, though. And yes, sure, if they're using some distribution with _very_ long support, they might have Bash 4.2 by default, but I'm guessing that's rare and anyone for uses those should be prepared to deal with obsolete software versions. Edited the phrasing anyway, since I seem to be going soft.

Answer (score 0):

`-v` expects a variable name, not a variable value.

```
[ ! -v hello ]
```

`[ -v "$hello" ]` returns true if the variable $hello contains a string that coincidentally is a name of a variable that's been set.

Comment: That does not answed the question. As mention, the code runs in one server not in the other and the variable is set. `[ -v "$hello" ]` gives exactly the same error!

Comment: What is the value of the variable?